# How can I seamlessly wrap map tiles around cylindrically?

Tags: math

I'm creating a game that takes place on a map, and the player should be able to scroll around the map. I'm using [real-world data from NASA](https://visibleearth.nasa.gov/images/74092/july-blue-marble-next-generation) as a 5700 by 2700 pixel image split into 4 smaller ones, each corresponding to a hemisphere:

How I split up the image: [image: img]

The player will be viewing the world through a camera, which is currently in a 4:3 aspect ratio, which can be moved around. Its height and width can be described as two variables x and y, currently at 480 and 360 respectively.

Model of the camera: [image: img]

In practice, the camera is "fixed" and instead the tiles move. The camera's center is described as two variables: xcam and ycam.
Currently, the 4 tiles move and hide flawlessly. The problem arises when the camera passes over the "edge" at 180 degrees latitude. What should happen is that the tiles on one side should show and move as if the world was a cylinder without any noticeable gaps. I update xcam by doing this equation to it:

```
xcam = ((xcam + (2700 - x) mod (5400 - x)) - (2700 - x)
```

And the tiles' centers update according to these equations (I will focus only on tiles 1 and 2 for simplicity):

```
tile1_x = xcam - 1350
tile1_y = ycam + 650
tile2_x = xcam + 1350
tile2_y = ycam + 650
```

Using this, whenever the camera moves past the leftmost edge of tile 1, it "skips" and instead of tile 1 still being visible with tile 2 in view, it moves enough so that tile 2's rightmost edge is in the camera's rightmost edge.

Here's what happens in reality: [image: img],

and here's what I want to happen: [image: img].

So, is there any way to update the equations I'm using (or even completely redo everything) so that I can get smooth wrapping?

Answer (score 0):

I think you unnecessarily hard-code a number of tiles and their sizes, and thus bind your code to those data. In my opinion it would be better to store them in some variables, so that they can be easily modified in one place if data ever changes. This also allows us to write a more flexible code.

So, let's assume we have variables:

```
// logical size of the whole Earth's map,
// currently 2 and 2
int ncols, nrows;

// single tile's size, currently 2700 and 1350
int wtile, htile;

// the whole Earth map's size
// always ncols*wtile and nrows*htile
int wmap, hmap;

Tile tiles[nrows][ncols];

// viewport's center in map coordinates
int xcam, ycam;

// viewport's size in map coordinates, currently 480 and 360
int wcam, hcam;
```

Whenever we update the player's position, we need to make sure the position falls within an allowed range. But, we need to establish the coordinates system first in order to define the allowed range. For example, if `x` values span from `0` to `wmap-1`, increasing rightwards (towards East), and `y` values span from `0` to `hmap-1`, increasing downwards (toward South), then:

```
// player's displacement
int dx, dy;

xcam = (xcam + dx) mod wmap
ycam = (ycam + dy) mod hmap
```

assures the camera position is always within the map. (Assumed the `mod` operator always returns non-negative value. Should it work like the C language `%` operator, which returns negative result for negative dividend, one needs to add a divisor first to make sure the first argument is non-negative: `xcam = (xcam + dx + wmap) mod wmap`, etc.)

If you'd rather like to have `xcam,ycam = 0,0` at the center of a map (that is, at the Greenwich meridian and the equator), then the allowed range would be `-wmap/2` through `wmap/2-1` for `x` and `-hmap/2` through `hmap/2 - 1` for `y`. Then:

```
xcam = (xcam + dx + wmap/2) mod wmap - wmap/2
ycam = (ycam + dy + hmap/2) mod hmap - hmap/2
```

More generally, let `x0, y0` denote the 'zero' position of camera relative to the upper-left corner of the map. Then we can update the camera position by transforming it to the map's coordinates, then shifting and wrapping, and finally transforming back to camera's coordinates:

```
xmap = xcam + x0
ymap = ycam + y0

xmap = (xmap + dx) mod wmap
ymap = (ymap + dy) mod hmap

xcam = xmap - x0
ycam = ymap - y0
```

or, more compactly:

```
xcam = (xcam + dx + x0) mod wmap - x0
ycam = (ycam + dy + y0) mod hmap - y0
```

Now, when we know the position of the viewport (camera) relative to the map, we need to fill it with the map tiles. And a new decision must be made here.

When we travel from Anchorage, Alaska (western hemisphere) to the North, we eventually reach the North Pole and then we'll find ourselves in the eastern hemisphere, headin South. If we proceed in the same direction, we'll get to Kuusamo, Norway, then Sankt Petersburg, Russia, then Kiev, Ukraine... But that would be a travel to the South! We usually do not describe it as a next part of the initial North route. Consequently, we do not show the part 'past the pole' as an upside-down extension of a map. Hence the map should never show tiles above row number `0` or below row `nrows-1`.

On the other hand, when we travel along circles of latitude, we smoothly cross the 0 and 180 meridians and switch between the eastern and western hemisphere. So if the camera view covers area on both sides of the left or right edge of the map, we need to continue filling the view with tiles from the other end of the `tiles` array. If we use a map scaled down, so that it is smaller than the viewport, we may even need to iterate that more than once!

The left edge of a camera view corresponds to the 'longitude' of `xleft = xcam - wcam/2` and the right one to `xrght = xcam + wcam/2`. So we can step across the viewport by the tile's width to find out appropriate columns and show them:

```
x = xleft
repeat
    show a column at x
    x = x + wtile
until x >= xrght
```

The 'show a column at `x`' part requires finding appropriate column, then iterating across the column to show corresponding tiles. Let's find out which tiles fit the camera view:

```
ytop = ycam - hcam/2
ybot = ycam + hcam/2

y=ytop
repeat
    show a tile at x,y
    y = y + htile
until y >= ybot
```

To show the tile we need to locate appropriate tile and then send it to appropriate position in the camera view.
However, we treat column number differently from the row number: columns wrap while rows do not:

```
row = y/htile
if (0 <= row) and (row < nrows) then
    col = (x/wtile) mod ncols
    xtile = x - (x mod wtile)
    ytile = y - (y mod htile)
    display tile[row][col] at xtile,ytile
endif
```

Of course `xtile` and `ytile` are our map-scale longitude and latitude, so the 'display tile at' routine must transform them to the camera view coordinates by subtracting the camera position from them:

```
xinwiev = xtile - xcam
yinview = ytile - ycam
```

and then apply the resulting values relative to the camera view's center at the displaying device (screen).

Another level of complication will appear if you want to implement zooming in and out the view, that is dynamic scaling of the map, but I'm sure you'll find out yourself which calculations will need applying the zoom factor for correct results. :)